# How to get a value in a JavaScript object by key

Tags: javascript

I have object and I would like to get the value of the id somehow by providing type = "EXTRA". Could someone help with this?

```
{
    "packages": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "type": "EXTRA",
            "name": "text",
            "extras": [
                {
                    "test": "1",
                    "test": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "234",
            "type": "BASE",
            "name": "text2",
            "extras": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Show your code and we will help you fix it :)

Comment: let searchedPackage = packages.find(package => package.type === 'EXTRA');
console.log(searchedPackage.id);

This should let you get the value of the id key. You can further complicate this by having a UI where the user selects the type and then this type value the user has selected is used inside of the find function. Furthermore, this looks aweful lot like JSON and not an actual object. Look into https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: I try to figure out how to get value from response in cypress. So far I try this:

```cy.request({
method:'GET',
url:"/test",
}).then((resp) => {
expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
cy.log(resp.body.find(x => x.type === 'EXTRA')?.id)
//or
cy.log(Object.keys(resp.body).find(x => resp.body[x] === "EXTRA")
})```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array

```
var arr = {
        "packages": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "type": "EXTRA",
                "name": "text",
                "extras": [
                    {
                        "test": "1",
                        "test": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "234",
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "text2",
                "extras": [],
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can use the find() method for what you need providing the 'EXTRA' value of type

```
var result = arr.packages.find(x => x.type === 'EXTRA');
```

Your Output

```
console.log(result.id); //123
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/1moru9y4/9/

Comment: I tried with this, and it works correctly, but when I need to get it from the response. It shows something like this: ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')```. I did not add that I am trying to do it in cypress. And i think better way, to save it, will be : ```var result = arr.packages.find(x => x.type === 'EXTRA')?.id```

Comment: you can save it like this as well if you prefer `var result2 = arr.packages.find(x => x.type === 'EXTRA').id;`

Comment: ok, when I added something like that, it started working:

```cy.request({ 
method:'GET', 
url:"/test", 
}).then((resp) => { 
let test = resp.body.packages.find(x => x.type === 'EXTRA')?.id
cy.log(test)
})```

Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of id, use this bro and keep a name of all objects bro : `objectName.packages[nameofobject.id]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).